# Jquery conflict, one script won't work with another

Tags: javascript, jquery, lavalamp

*I have jquery script for menu and other for gallery, how to enable both of them to work? Below is my code*

**I also have some expanding box problem on the li element,  whit thi explanation:**

Any content that does not fit in a fixed-width or -height box causes the box to expand to fit the content rather than letting the content overflow.

Affects: Internet Explorer 6.0
Likelihood: Likely

**And also double float margin bug error:**

When a margin is applied to a floated box on the same side as the direction of the float, the margin is doubled. This bug only affects the first float in a row of one or more floats.

Affects: Internet Explorer 6.0
Likelihood: Very Likely

It is very urgent,pls help!

**SCRIPT FOR MENU BAR**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.lavalamp.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/image_fade.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#lava_menu").lavaLamp({
        fx: "backout",
        speed: 700
      });
    });
</script>
```

**SCRIPT FOR GALLERY**

```
 <script type="text/javascript"src="../../hisasann-jStack/js/jquery.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="../../hisasann-jStack/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../hisasann-jStack/js/jStack.js"></script>

        <!-- syntax -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://hisasann.com/housetect/js/dp.SyntaxHighlighter/Styles/SyntaxHighlighter.css" type="text/css" />  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://hisasann.com/housetect/js/dp.SyntaxHighlighter/Scripts/shCore.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://hisasann.com/housetect/js/dp.SyntaxHighlighter/Scripts/shBrushXml.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://hisasann.com/housetect/js/dp.SyntaxHighlighter/Scripts/shBrushCss.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://hisasann.com/housetect/js/dp.SyntaxHighlighter/Scripts/shBrushPhp.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://hisasann.com/housetect/js/dp.SyntaxHighlighter/Scripts/shBrushJScript.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://hisasann.com/housetect/js/dp.SyntaxHighlighter/Scripts/shBrushCss.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://hisasann.com/housetect/js/dp.SyntaxHighlighter/Scripts/shBrushJava.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://hisasann.com/housetect/js/dp.SyntaxHighlighter/Scripts/shBrushRuby.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(function() {
                dp.SyntaxHighlighter.ClipboardSwf = 'http://hisasann.com/housetect/js/dp.SyntaxHighlighter/Scripts/clipboard.swf';
                dp.SyntaxHighlighter.HighlightAll('code');

                // fadeInOut
                $("#logo").fadeOut().fadeIn();

                // smooth scroller
                $("a[href^=#]").click(function() {
                    var hash = this.hash;
                    if(!hash || hash == "#")
                        return false;
                    $($.browser.safari ? 'body' : 'html')
                        .animate({scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top}, 1500, "easeInOutBounce");
                    return false;
                });
            });

            var options = {
                isClickAnimation: true,
                isPositionRandom: true,
                durationOut: 300,
                durationIn: 200,
                easingOut: "easeInOutBack",
                easingIn: "easeOutBounce",
                moveLeft: 250,
                moveTop: 150,
                opacityOut: 0.6,
                opacityIn: 1,
                delay: 10,
                direction: "next",
                callback: function() {}
            };

            $(window).bind("load", function() {
                // jStack
                var jstack = $("#imageBox").jStack(options);
                $("#next").click(function() {
                    jstack.next();
                });

                $("#prev").click(function() {
                    jstack.prev();
                });
                $("#shuffle").click(function() {
                    jstack.shuffle();
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Comment: One question per post, please. What problem are you having getting the menu and gallery scripts to work together?

Comment: Why are you loading jQuery twice? What works for one will surely work for the other.

Comment: I thought that is linked problem that's way I wrote everything. The problem is within menu bar (lava lamp)  hover floating highlighter  it doesn't appear at all. I tried but one jquery  wont work for another, I don't know wath is problem.

Comment: If I call noConflict(), again works just menu or gallery function, I don't know how to enable both of them.

Comment: @user2101190 Please Refer this link for Jquery conflict http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="../../hisasann-jStack/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

if im not mistaken, both of them are jquery library?, they probably has conflict with each other if they are loaded on the same page, this problem occured to me, what i did was removed one of the library,

Comment: Like I said I already tried that. On removing jquery.min.Lava lamp is in the same problem with highlighter, and on removing jquery hisasann-jStack gallery buttons previous and next are dead spot.

Comment: try removing both and link an online jquery library,